# jQuery sortable('disable') from start event not entirely working like expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, sortables

The below code does not fully disable the sortables on the start event. It will add the classes `ui-sortable-disabled` and `ui-state-disabled` to the sortable elements, but it doesn't disable the functionality - in other words, the sortables look disabled, but they still accept the dragged item and behave like they are enabled.

```
var assignedSortables;
var startDrag = function(event, ui) { 
    assignedSortables.each(function() {$(this).sortable('disable');});
};

var stopDrag = function(event, ui) { 
    assignedSortables.each(function() {$(this).sortable('enable');});
};

assignedSortables = $(".my-sortable-containers").sortable({
    connectWith: '.my-sortable-containers',
    start: startDrag,
    stop: stopDrag
});
```

The reason I want to do this is on drag start is because I might need to disable other connected sortables that already contain the item being dragged (I stripped out the logic in order to simplify). Is this a bug or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not checked to see if the jQuery library has "fixed" this since I asked the question, what I did instead was use the mousedown and mouseup events to disable and enable

```
$(".myDraggableContainer").mousedown(functionToDisableTheCorrectSortables).mouseup(functionToEnableSortables);
```

Doing it this way does in fact disable the receiving sortables fully

Comment: Hi! I was just playing around with hiding the .placeholder in the over event, but it's just a visual hack, I still need to remove the item etc. I tried your answer but can't get it to work? See my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tunafish/m32XW/1/ What am I missing? In this example I just want to disable the right list when dragging items from the left.

Comment: Got it now!! I was doing the mouse events on the list not the items. See: http://jsfiddle.net/tunafish/m32XW/3/ What a relief, now I can get of my crazy hacks :-) *Bounty* cheers

Comment: this nearly worked for me. I can see the sortable div get a class of ui-sortable-disabled but if it already has another element in it then I can 'trick' it in to accepting the non allowed element.
I had to stick with closing the sortable on the activate event if the dragged item is a non allowed element.

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the same issue. I was able to get the connected sortable that I wanted to disable to disable (for reals) by calling the 'refresh' method on the initiating sortable.

So, inside your start callback would be something like:

```
$connectedList.sortable('disable');
$(ui.sender).sortable('refresh');
```

I guess that internally the list grabs the set of connected and non-disabled lists before the start event is triggered and does not check to see if that list changes after start is triggered.

Comment: This worked for me and in my case I was using 2 sortables in an Angular JS app so I was able to disable one when it shouldn't be allowed to accept an item, call refresh the source sortable and the refresh was the trick, without that the disable didn't work on it's own. Running jQuery 1.8.2

Comment: The key is calling "refresh" on the *source* sortable... counterintuitive!

Comment: The above code should be used in the ***activate*** event of the connected list . FYI when u disable the sorted list u wont recieve the ***deactivate*** event call